# Edeliver: tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, tput, edeliver

I'm trying to do automatic deployment in Jenkins machine with edeliver to our production. There seems to be something wrong with my build machine.

> mix edeliver build release --verbose
>   --branch=70818f1f707545aaec17e0ca3daa035e7eea4746 tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
>   tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified tput: No value for $TERM
>   and no -T specified tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified tput:
>   No value for $TERM and no -T specified tput: No value for $TERM and no
>   -T specified tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified tput: No value for $TERM and no -T
>   specified tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified tput: No value
>   for $TERM and no -T specified tput: No value for $TERM and no -T
>   specified tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified tput: No value
>   for $TERM and no -T specified tput: No value for $TERM and no -T
>   specified
>
> BUILDING RELEASE OF INTEGRATION APP ON BUILD HOST
>
> -----> Authorizing hosts
>   -----> Ensuring hosts are ready to accept git pushes
>
> A remote command failed on:
>
> ubuntu@ec2-54-93-168-21.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
>
> Output of the command is shown above and the command executed on that
>   host is printed below for debugging purposes:
>
> FAILED with exit status 255:
>
> ```
> set -e
> if [ ! -d /tmp/edeliver/integration/build ]
> then
>   mkdir -p /tmp/edeliver/integration/build
>   cd /tmp/edeliver/integration/build
>   git init 
>   git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
> else
>   cd /tmp/edeliver/integration/build
>   git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
> fi
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Need configure elixir in build machine.
In jenkins before the execute edeliver write this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Check out the machine credentials and try again.

Comment: That's good advice but would that cause this specific error? I can't see how it can

Comment: Jenkins use a other shell, need specification use bash becacuse edeliver need use to bash or shz. And credentials is very important for authoritzing hosts